# Words typed backwards on HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, textinput

I have a form on a website, with a number of input controls, e.g.

```
Q1 <input name="question1" id="question1" type="text" />
<br>
Q2 <input name="question2" id="question2" type="text" />
```

There is javascript attached to the controls to display the character count.

```
   $('input[type="text"]').on("keyup", function () {
                $(this).parents(".text").find(".characters").html($(this).val().length);
   });

   $("textarea").on("keyup", function () {
                $(this).parents(".text").find(".characters").html($(this).val().length);
   });
```

A number of users report that when they type into the form the text is backwards, at a sentence level (not a letter level), e.g. they type "This is a test" but the text is entered into the textbox input control as "test a is This".

This only affects a tiny percentage of users, and they are the general public so I have very little other information available, though it *seems* all instances have occurred when using a mobile. When it does affect the user it seems to affect all text controls on the page.

If this were at a letter level, I'd look to unicode and the HTML dir tag, but it's at a word level (which should be unaffected by unicode direction and the dir tag) so I'm stumped.

Comment: Show your code, reduced to [mcve] form, because you have JS tied to those inputs and you're not showing that JS right now. Remember to (re)read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: *'There's some simple javascript hooked up in keydown and blur events for validation.'* You'll have to show the validation for concrete help.